Redirect route in controller with jquery post method not work?
In my project, I implement this function:
public function createGuest(Request $request) {
            $check1 = AdminUser::where('username', $request['user_name'])->count();
            $previous = "localhost:8000";
            if ($check1 > 0) return null; // user exists

            $user               = new AdminUser();
            $user->username     = $request['username'];
            $user->password     = $request['password'];
            $user->save();
            $user->roles()->attach('3');

            return redirect($previous);
}

and for the route, I define this one:
    $router->post('/create-guest', [GuestController::class, "createGuest"])->name('createGuest');

After running the jQuery code:
<body>
       <form method="post" role="form" action="/create-guest" class="php-email-form">
        ..... HTML 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="signUps()">Đăng ký</button>
    </form>
</body>
<script>
    async function signUps() {
        let url = "/create-guest";
        let username        = $("input[name=username]").val();
        let password        = $("input[name=password]").val();

        let data = {
            "_token"        : "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            "username"          : username,
            "password"          : password,
        }
        let res = await $.post(url, data); //errors come here
    }
</script>

The res variable now has all of the HTML pages like when I click into it and then not redirect anymore.
res = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Ogani Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Ogani, unica, creative, html">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="LOV3ISszq8gGw0ooUfoQZb39h16OX2y7TXw60us0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>This is home page</title>

    
    <div id="fb-root"></div> ...."

and notify 500 (Internal Server Error)
Is it wrong if I dealt with redirect()->to() wrong? Why I can't redirect()->to() with async POST method in js?
EDIT:
I realize I misunderstood the URL in JQuery, it should be  let url = "/create-guest";, Thank you for that, but, I am sure the error isn't it.

Check your laravel.logs to see what is happening why you are getting an error 500. As for you trying to redirect, you would need something like a windows.location.replace like shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004

As for which URL to redirect, check the value of your res

AJAX expects JSON response. redirect function returns HTML response. If you send POST request from frontend file, you have to organize it in a way you expect what to get. Change controller's method code to return some JSON response and then act in JS code accordingly.

@Tpojka In fact, I intended to do what you said, but I don't know why redirect()->() can't be used in this scenario ?
